# enforce order of function calls?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Say I have a abstract base class and I want to have a pure virtual method which must be implemented by the derived class but I want to make sure that the derived method calls functions in a particular order what could I do to enforce it ?

I.E

```
base class
virtual void doABC()=0;
virtual void A()=0;
virtual void B()=0;
virtual void C()=0;


// must call ABC in the correct order 
derived class public base
void doABC();
```

This is just so I have a better understanding on how to design my classes to enforce someone to use my class correctly.

Comment: Why is `doABC` virtual? If it were non-virtual you would be safe from people overriding it and changing the behaviour that you want to enforce.

Comment: I want to create a design of a base class that will make sure that anyone who inherits from my class has to do things in a correct order. I could use the constructor but I want to make sure that when doABC is called that is what they are doing without me having to actually implement A B and C. If that makes sense

Comment: @gda2004 Yes, this is exactly what you achieve when making `doABC` non-virtual (and not redefining it in derived classes, of course). Then the order in `doABC` is completely out of control of the derived classes, since they all use the base implementation. It's only the actual `A`, `B` and `C` methods that they reimplement. Nobody says each and every function of a base class has to be virtual and needs to be reimplemented, only the ones that make sense, but when every child class just calls `A`, `B` and `C` in order, it doesn't make sense for them to reimplement `doABC` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two particular ways, depending on whether you go with inheritance or parameterization.

If you with inheritance, it is the [`Template Method`](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/template_method.html) pattern:

```
class Base {
public:
    void doit() {
        this->do1();
        this->do2();
    }
private:
    virtual void do1() = 0;
    virtual void do2() = 0;
};
```

And if you go with parameterization, it is the [`Strategy`](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/strategy.html) pattern:

```
class Strategy {
public:
    virtual void do1() = 0;
    virtual void do2() = 0;
};

void doit(Strategy& s) {
    s.do1();
    s.do2();
}
```

From the website:

> *Strategy* is like *Template Method* except in its granularity. [Coplien, C++ Report, Mar 96, p88]
>
> *Template Method* uses inheritance to vary part of an algorithm. *Strategy* uses delegation to vary the entire algorithm. [GoF, p330]
>
> *Strategy* modifies the logic of individual objects. *Template Method* modifies the logic of an entire class. [Grand, p383]

I recommend you familiarize yourself with them.

Answer (score 13):

You're looking for the **template method pattern**:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Something along these lines:

```
class BaseAlgorithm
{
protected:
    virtual void firstStep() = 0;
    virtual void secondStep() = 0;
    virtual void finalStep() = 0;
public:
    void runAlgorithm()
    {
        firstStep();
        secondStep();
        finalStep();
    }
};

class ConcreteAlgorithm : BaseAlgorithm
{
    virtual void firstStep() {};
    virtual void secondStep() {};
    virtual void finalStep() {};
};
```

You basically force extending classes to implement all intermediate steps, but you keep them `protected` or `private` - document this - and only call `runAlgorithm()`, which ties the smaller pieces together.

Comment: Also in general you should keep your public functions non-virtual, and implement the polymorphic behavior of the classes via protected virtual functions. As well as the above enforcement of order, it will also allow you to check pre/post conditions and carry out common code chunks between "steps".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer could be if You remove virtual from doABC(), so that it can not be derived by child class. Call the virtual methods inside doABC() in correct order.