# How to establish a strong before after relationship between two public functions

Tags: java, design-patterns

In the following code  of A* algorithm [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38376/a-search-algorithm), I have 2 functions `setG` and `calcF`, such that -

1. `setG` must be called before `calcF`
   &&
2. `calcF` must be called after `setG`

in other words, simply calling `setG` without calling `calcF` later is incorrect.
Also, simply calling `calcF` without calling `setG` before is incorrect. 
Calling `calcF` before `setG` is incorrect.

How can this rule be enfored to the client ?

A similar question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256627/how-to-enforce-sequence-in-function-calls), but there is a minute difference. This question is more stricter in conditions.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to call calcF immediately after calling setG? In other words, why not make one function that calls setG and then calls calcF.

Comment: Something similar to a "cancellation token" (i.e: return some generated value from `setG` that must be passed to `calcF`, with a type name that makes it super obvious). You could even make `setG` lazy such that it doesn't do the work until you call `calcF`. Otherwise, assertions of some kind.

Comment: Can't you just wrap them into a single function which takes all the input paramethers and calls your two functions in the right order?

Comment: @elbuild I can, but since they are performing two distinct operations, it would create a single function with two reposibilities, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Well, if your assertion is that setG must be called exactly once, then later calcF is called exactly once, after calcF is called the process can repeat, and nothing in between has any side effects, then the general means of doing this is to use one function. You need not put all the code in one function, but the other functions should be protected/private. There's no reason to have two public functions if they can never validly be called separately and there are no other side-effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first idea would be to merge those functions into one function `setGAndCalcF()`:

```
private void setG(int g);

private void calcF(T destination);

public void setGAndCalcF(int g, T destination) {
    setG(g);
    calcF(destination);
}
```

If this is not feasible you can implement runtime checks (plus documentation) into `setG()` and `calcF()` which would throw an Exception (e.g. `IllegalStateException`).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Markus is for me correct. Howvere if you want know the design pattern, you should use **a pipe**:

```
 public Holder setG(G g)

 public void calcF(F f, Holder H)
```