# Enforce Interface Implementations to Run a Method First

Tags: java, interface

Given an interface

```
interface ImplementMe {
    // some other methods omitted for the question 
    default void methodFreeToReimplement() {
        methodMustRun();
        // and then the default or custom code
    }
    default void methodMustRun() {
        // do something important
    }
}
```

There is a method `methodMustRun()` with a default implementation that must run first (don't care if they override this for now) whenever `methodFreeToReimplement()` is called.

Implementations of this interface are free to override `methodFreeToReimplement()`. Obviously, if they do not choose to override this then the default implementation will run `methodMustRun()`. But if they do, it is required to run `methodMustRun()` first in any of the overridden versions of `methodFreeToReimplement()`.

Is there a way in the programming language itself (not via comments in BOLD, not via code review, etc. policies) to enforce this? i.e. the result is either the program runs with the requirement above met or the program doesn't run/compile.

OK to answer no if that is the limitation of the programming language THEN a solution (including not using interfaces or even suggest another programming language that can enforce this).

Comment: You might find some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256627/how-to-enforce-sequence-in-function-calls